# multiple queries running at the same time WITH(NOLOCK)

Tags: sql-server

Considering a highly active remote database in constant use; Would 2 or perhaps more concurrently running queries returning around **30m** records but using  **WITH(NOLOCK)** in the query  make the system unusable?

**Highly Active:** Around 200 users with varying queries ranging from 1 record queries to maximum as above.

**Constant:** 18/7

**Unusable:** 5-15 minute delays. External apps or users not being able to reach the DB to query.

Comment: Define "unusable". Define "highly active". Define "constant use".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to investigate your downtime 'unusable' as appropiate. Guessing will not work. There are many situations that can make a server 'unusable', like:

- database growth
- log growth
- core dump
- scheduler exhaustion
- many more

Other times the server can be simply 'slow' and appear unresponsive. 200 queries scanning nilly-willy 30 million rows table can lead to [scheduler exhaustion](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/aschenbrenner/2011/10/25/troubleshooting-threadpool-waits/). You will need to properly investigate. [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) is a good methodology to use (for instance it would correctly identify scheduler exhaustion mentioned above).

As for NOLOCK: there is never a valid reason to use NOLOCK. Your users [see incorrect data right now](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx). Consider using [row versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177404%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean

> make the system less unusable for **other** users while selecting 30m records

no, the `WITH(NOLOCK)` has no effect whatsoever.

Note that selecting 30m records in by itself is likely going to be a very I/O sensitive operation so I wouldn't go willy nilly in selecting that much records but the `WITH(NOLOCK)` for all intents and purposes only affects the performance of the one doing the select.

Comment: I was just curious if the other user's and apps that use the same database will notice that 30m records were being queried. For example, if the db would slow down so much that apps would get timeouts and people get slower reactions? It takes a noticable time (Around 10 mins) for the query to finish.

Comment: That very much depends on what hardware configuration *(read money)* you are willing to throw at it and you should definitely do some stress testing to find out but my first reaction would be: yes, it will be noticable.